# Access lat and long of geometry field

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, geometry

I've defined a geometry field within the migrations. There are already entries in this table.
Now i want to display the coordinates. The object is read, but i don't know how to access lat/long within twig.

Any ideas?

Dominik

Comment: Can you please add more details about your "geometry" field and model, and where is it that you want to access it from?

Comment: i use laravel - here i want to display the lat/long on the view. The Eloquent ORM is here used as the mapper.

Answer (score 0):

If your table contains point objects,  you can do this

```
 SELECT ST_X(point_object) X, ST_Y(point_object) Y
   FROM table
  WHERE whatever
```

If your objects are polygons or collections of  polygons, you might have to use something like this to get a single x,y from each object.

```
 SELECT ST_X(ST_CENTROID(poly)) X, ST_Y(ST_CENTROID(poly)) Y
   FROM table
  WHERE whatever
```

It's hard to tell you more without knowing what's in your geometry objects.